# Архитектура игры. Отделить логику от анимации

Tags: разработка-игр, архитектура

Есть 2D игра с видом сверху в жанре RPG в реальном времени. Игра пишется на Java с использованием библиотеки Swing. Планируется переписать часть ответственную за отрисовку с использованием JOGL, а также в дальнейшем перенести игру на Android.

Поэтому я старался отделить логику от представления таким образом, чтобы в одном месте находилась чистая логика которая ничего не знает о том, что кто-то собирается её отрисовать и в другом месте находился код занимающийся отображением, который через геттеры получал состояние модели и сам решал какие данные модели отрисовать и как это сделать. Мне удавалось соблюдать этот принцип пока не появилась необходимость анимировать изображения.

Что требовалось от анимации: во время игрового процесса у меня должна была быть возможность ставить анимацию на паузу, возобновлять её, менять скорость проигрывания, выбирать анимацию для объекта в зависимости от состояния его модели, проигрывать не всю анимацию а только часть.

Где возникла проблема:

1.) Получалось, что каждый объект должен хранить номер текущего кадра, кол-во кадров для данного состояния,и скорость проигрывания анимации для данного состояния. Номер кадра и скорость проигрывания индивидуальны для каждого объекта. Поэтому модель стала хранить данные относящиеся к отображению.

2.) В некоторых моментах логика стала зависеть от анимации, т.к. некоторые действия могут быть выполнены только после того, как проиграется соответствующая анимация.

3.) Анимация для каждого вида объекта хранятся в виде одного изображения, которое при запуске игры считывается и программно нарезается. Чтобы выполнить нарезку необходимо знать размер кадра, какие состояния объекта анимируются, кол-во кадров для каждого такого состояния, в какой последовательности на изображении изображены эти состояния. Этой задачей занимается отображение, но часть необходимых ей данных стала хранить модель, при этом объект модели хранящий эту информацию может быть ещё не создан.

Вопрос: где лучше хранить данные необходимые для проигрывания анимации и подготовки изображений? Каким образом сохранить независимость модели от отображения с учетом выше названых трудностей?

Пожалуйста, подскажите какое архитектурное решение лучше подойдет в данном случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Это не совсем верно. Модель не стала хранить "данные относящиеся к отображению". Наоборот - в модель вошли новые данные состояния. Теперь объект знает не только о своем положении, но и о том в какой фазе сейчас находится его действие. А анимация это только показывает.
2. Разделяйте анимацию на анимацию, и на ключи/триггеры. Ключи и тригерры - это свойства логики модели. Анимация - часть отображения.
3. Очередность создания вроде бы достаточно простая вещь. Проблемы с кросс-зависимостями, как-раз, индикатор проблем взаимного проникновения частей систем друг в друга.

Где хранить данные? - все что относится к отображению - в отображении. Все что нужно для работы логики модели (т.е. для работы без отображения, в т.н. headless режиме) - в данных модели.

---

Вообще, хороший тест на разделение логики и отображения - можете ли вы заменить вывод графики с OpenGL на D3D не поменяв модель? А на консоль и ASCII арт? А запустить игру в headless режиме? И ничего не поломается и не изменится с т.з. модели? Если на каждый вопрос вы ответили да - разделение есть и оно хорошее.

---

В целом, не увлекайтесь ранними абстрактными оптимизациями архитектуры. Лучший вариант - делайте порт на другую палтформу. Процесс вам сам подскажет, что надо вынести в общее, что в модель, что в отображение и т.д.

Comment: Насчет первого пункта - кол-во кадров анимации для определенного состояния(или как вы их назвали - фаза действия) определятся тем, сколько их решил нарисовать художник. Т.е. определяется отображением. Хотя возможно я ошибаюсь. Просто в моем представлении отображение - это абсолютно все связанное с тем, что рисуется на экране. Правильно ли я понимаю что нужно понимать под отображением?

Comment: Количество кадров анимации - это свойство отображения. Модель должна знать только ее длину (в тиках, например) и ключи действий (тоже в тиках тогда).

Comment: Если сделать длину анимации свойством модели и измерять её в тиках, то по моему эти данные не всегда будут нужны именно модели. Пример1 : есть маг кастующий атакующее заклинание. Заклинание "выстреливает" только после того, как завершена анимация его подготовки. Эти данные можно переместить в модель создав для мага состояния - атакует и готовит_атаку. Для второго задать максимальное время и отслеживать время выполнения. Эти данные логично разместить в модели, т.к. информация о длительности используется её. Также например - если маг готовя заклинание и получил урон - прервать подготовку заклин.

Comment: Пример2: возьмем  анимацию горения костра. Допустим для неё есть 5 кадров и общее время анимации 250 милесекунд. Можно в модели костра создать состояние одна_фаза_горения, фаза вспыхвания_костра и тоже отслеживать для них время. Но эти данные самой моделью никак не используются и они по сути её не нужны. Эти данные нужны только отображению и логичней было бы разместить их там. Но для каждого костра эти данные уникальны и нужно в тоже время, чтобы было понятно к какому именно костру относятся эти данные. И опять получается, что данные которые использ. только  отображением хранятся в модели.

Comment: Пример 1: модель должна знать длину анимации, чтобы по ее окончании начать другую, или, например, проверить была анимация прервана или нет. Не обязательно разбивать анимацию на куски (может пострадать качество анимации), можно обойтись ключами. Пример 2: Все верно, и это хранить в модели и не надо. Взять то же горение, в анимации может быть ключ для звуковой системы, в какой-то момент издать треск или другой звук, может быть ключ для модели - в какой момент уменьшить здоровье дома. Ключи для звука - не относятся к модели, т.к. звук это "отображение". Ключи для модели - нужны модели.

Comment: Но на самом деле чуть-чуть наоборот - это модель должна задать длину действия, а анимация - подгоняется под это. Если модели нужно, чтобы лучник выстрелил за 1,7сек и чтобы стрела отправилась в полет в начале действия - то анимация под это делается, а не наоборот (представляете, елси аниматор сделал стрельбу длиной 7сек и стрела выпускается только в конце .. теперь лучники в нашей игре ни на что не годны из-за медлительности и легкости прерывания действия...)

Comment: Насчет примера с магом - мне кажется хорошим будет следующее решение. Длина действия "подготовка заклинания" допустим имеет длину 500 миллисекунд. Модель знает это, а также помнит сколько миллисекунд прошло с начала выполнения этого действия, но предоставляет эту информацию анимации в виде дробного числа полученного делением текущего времени действия на его длину. Т.е. число находится в диапозоне от 0 до 1. Тогда отображению даже не нужно хранить текущий кадр анимации - зная кол-во кадров и значение дробного числа его легко вычислить.

Comment: Но с костром всё равно непонятно. К примеру мы имеем 5 костров на сцене. И не хотелось бы чтобы анимация их горения была абсолютно синхронна. Тогда нужно хранить информацию о текущем кадре для каждого костра. По вашему совету - её не следует хранить в модели, т.к. эта инф. моделью никак не используется. Но если мы будем хранить её в отображении, тогда помимо  множества числовых переменных обозначающих текущий кадр каждого конкретного костра нам нужно будет хранить инф. и том,  к какому костру какая перменная относится. Как это можно  лучше реализовать? И правильно ли я понял вашу мысль?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75793/discussion-between-kromster-and-bakuard).